# Passing str as parameter to class definition? Defining a separate class for key for sorted?

Tags: python

I'm learning and Python and am trying to understand the code below

```
class LargerNumKey(str):
    def __lt__(x, y):
        return x+y > y+x
        
class Solution:
    def largestNumber(self, nums):
        largest_num = ''.join(sorted(map(str, nums), key=LargerNumKey))
        return '0' if largest_num[0] == '0' else largest_num
```

What I understand is that we are sorting a list, and we are passing the class LargerNumKey as the comparator.

The idea is that we are given a list of ints, and we convert these ints to strings. We are sorting the list of now strings in an order such that the concatenation of all the strings in the list would produce the largest number.

Thus, when sorting, a string a is considered larger than string b when ab > ba. However due to my unfamiliarity with Python I have several questions about this code

1. What does it mean to have str as the argument passed to the class definition of LargerNumKey?
2. And why is it necessary to define a completely new class rather than just a function to be passed as key to sorted?
3. I understand that `_lt_` is defining the less than operator for the LargerNumKey class. But I usually see `__lt__(self, other)`. So in this case is x representing self?

Comment: SO requires that each question contain only one question statement. Please update your question so that only one question is asked. I suggest that you retain only question #2 since the other two questions are really duplicates, where the answers can be easily found with a search.

Comment: (3) yes, it is self.

Comment: (2) you can try to use function if you like. But I'm not sure if it will work the same. It converts to object which has own method `<`  but using only function you can convert to another string which will still use standard `<`

Comment: (1) it is not argument - it is Inheritance - it will resize definition of `str`

Answer (score 1):

1. In briefly, when you pass a type or class as argument to another class, it means inheritance and your `LargerNumKey` class inherit all methods from str class such as split and others. (it is like `:` in C++ or C#)
2. It's necessary because you want to modify compare itself not just getattr.
   let's find it using an example:
   assume that you have a`list[list]` like `[[1, 4], [3, 2]]`, and want to compare them based on second element of each list, you can write your code such as:

```
sorted([[1, 4], [3, 2]], key = lambda x: x[1])
```

but in your case you want to modify your element as there is both x and y in definition. so, you define a new class that has a `__lt__` method.
let's check what your method do:

```
class LargerNumKey(str):
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self + other > other + self


class Solution:
    @staticmethod
    def largest_number(nums):
        largest_num = ''.join(sorted(map(str, nums), key=LargerNumKey))
        return '0' if largest_num[0] == '0' else largest_num


Solution.largest_number([2, 3, 9])
```

first it convert all `nums` elements to `str` to can join . then define a key: `LargerNumKey`... actually, python act with key such as a function: `LargerNumKey(e1)`. I mean when it want to compare two elements for sort `e1 < e2` it compare in your defined manner: `LargerNumKey(e1) < LargerNumKey(e2)`

you overloaded `<` in your derived class, so it compare them with your manner.

3. Yes, as I did in my code, `x` is `self` and `y` is `other`.